# how can I cross-browserize the following css3 moz snippet?

Tags: css, webkit

I'm new to css3 and would greatly appreciate if someone could give me the various browser versions for the following:

`background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FDFAFB, #F9F7F7 50%,#F0EDED) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent`

While other css methods can be adjusted by just changing "moz" to "webkit" etc, the various browsers seem to have very different rules for linear background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) site will help generate one, and then will give you the code for all combinations of well-known browsers.

Take a look.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I had seen that site, but I don't see a way to "plug in" the snippet I already have to generate the others...

Comment: theres a button on the bottom of the website, under the place where you can copy and paste your created gradient from, that says "import from css" -- you can paste your rule in there and it will create the other versions for you